# ¿Por qué no funciona firebase en mi servidor nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, firebase

Verán, tengo este código

```
var email = req.body.correo;
var pass = req.body.pass;
var firebase = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./prueba-064cb79dba28.json");

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://prueba-b81ec.firebaseio.com"
});

firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error) {

        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;

    });

}
```

he estado ojeando la documentación, primero tuve un error de método depreciado con la librería firebase, el servidor me mandó un mensaje de error diciéndome que usara ésta, sin embargo no funciona, no crea el usuario, ya verifiqué que el email y clave se envían.

```
POST /app/firebase 500 4032.168 ms - 1301
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
at new View (C:\Users\Michel-       Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:62:11)
at EventEmitter.render (C:\Users\Michel-Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:569:12)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Michel-Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:960:7)
at C:\Users\Michel-Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\app.js:53:7
at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Michel-Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Michel-Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:310:13)
at C:\Users\Michel-Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Michel-Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (C:\Users\Michel-Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\Michel-Pc\Documents\GitHub\disenador\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
```

este es el codigo de error de consola.

Comment: Y qué error te da? Podrías poner `console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);` dentro del catch?

Comment: PD: tienes un paréntesis final, en tu código, que no corresponde.

Comment: Saludos amenadiel, ya actualice, la llave al final corresponde al cierre de la función que la contiene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resuelto, ha sido por completo mi culpa, estaba usando el método createUserWithEmailAndPassword con firebase-admin cuando este método funciona es con la librería normal firebase, lo pongo por si a alguien le llega a pasar ;)

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
var config = {
apiKey: "AIza...",
authDomain: "...",
databaseURL: "...",

}; 
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Así es como debí haber configurado